# Searching in loaded file in Python

Tags: python, string, find

I'm trying to categorize information contained in text files, but I came across a strange problem: I load the file, put the information into a variable (which is a string) and when I try to use str.find() to search keywords within, I always get -1. If I print out the contents of the variable, explicitly put it into a variable and use str.find() the same way, I get the correct results. Both variable has the same contents, they are both strings, yet one of them is unsearchable. What do I do wrong? It's driving me crazy.

Sample code:

```
f=open('D:/test.txt','r')
print(f.read()) 
var1=f.read()
print(type(var1)) #<class 'str'>
print(str.find(var1,"name")) #gives -1
var2='{"_id": "12345", "name": "Bob", "Age": 30}' #copied manually from the first print

print(type(var2)) #<class 'str'> #gives 18
```

var1.find("name") doesn't work either. I'm using Python 3.6 and PyCharm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing `print(f.read()) ` and see if it works then. Also, try `print(var1)` in both scenarios. I have a feeling you'll find the first time (when you still have `print(f.read())`) `var1` will be empty

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're facing is due to your first `print(f.read())` line.
Calling `f.read()` extracts all the data from the file, so the file read position will be at the end. The following `read` won't return anything, because you already reached the end of file.

Removing the line should fix your issue.
Another solution would be to add `f.seek(0)` before `var1=f.read()`, which resets the file read position to the beginning of the file.

Comment: And you are absolutely right... I still don't really get why I couldn't search once it was copied to a separate variable, but thank you.

Comment: It was never copied to `var1`, it was always empty. You can search `var2` because you manually initialize it, but the result of the first `read` is printed and discarded